# Setting raster cells equal to zero to no data in Rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio

Given a random raster tif file, I want to set all cells which have a value of 0, to 'no data' using Python/rasterio. I just cant seem to find documentation about this simple operation.

```py
import rasterio

src = rasterio.open('some_grid.tif')
...........
```

With R's raster package, with which I'm way more literate, I would perform this operation like this:

```r
library(raster)

rast <- raster('some_grid.tif')
rast[rast == 0] <- NA
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Similar syntax in Python, first read in the tif file to a numpy array. array==0 produces a boolean array, which can then be used as an index mask for setting the desired values to NAN.

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

with rasterio.open('some_grid.tif') as src:
    array = src.read(1)

array[array==0] = np.nan
```

Comment: Could you add a little more context and explanation to your answer? A code-only answer is not as useful as an answer which explains what this code does. That way it can also help future readers.

Comment: Thanks, added some description of the masking process.

Comment: But in the case of integer datatype raster, the error, `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer` will occur.